# How to extend dict in ansible, not overwriting it?

Tags: ansible, configuration-management

Let's say I have an ansible role which being imported in any place will clone repositories to specified path, called "git_role", for example.

It's mechanism, clone repositories for projects doing by one role when it's inlcuded to playbook.

And it's doing by assigning dict like

```
repos:
  name_of_repo:
    url: "git@myrepo.com"
    path: "/path/on/local_system"
    branch: "branch_to_checkout"
```

And this dict on "git_role" which doing clone repo handled like this:

```
- name: Clone repositories
  git:
    repo: "{{ item['value']['url'] }}"
    dest: "{{ item['value']['path'] }}"
    accept_hostkey: yes
  loop: "{{ repos | dict2items }}"
```

I want that "repos" dict can be easy extended by any other roles. For example role "A" define dict "repos" with repo needed for role "A", and after I imported role "git_role" along with role "A" in playbook. "git_role" will look into extended dict "repos" and going clone all described repos.

Role "B" for example can described another repo in dict "repos" and "git_role" in that case clone that repos needed for role "B" and so on.

Ansible dy default has :

```
hash_behaviour=replace
```

And I don't want change it, as developers don't suggest it. [reddit conversation](https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/a7x92q/in_which_case_hash_behaviourmerge_can_become/)

I look into "combine" but it also override dict...

Who can suggest right painless way to extend one particular dict by any sources?

Not even dict must. There can be any data source which "git_role" can consume and clone all specified repos.

Comment: You can create a task in each role to modify the existing fact, or abstract it to a role that will be included in every role providing additional dependencies. In this case it is easier to make a list of repos, not dict. Also I suppose that clone repositories task will have to be a handler, to run after all others...

Comment: List of dicts maybe? Because list is flat, and I need a key values data structure.
Also cloning all repos after all others is not best way, repos should be cloned at time of running particular roles because in that role can be a task based on just cloned (they think) repo. Also clone all repos at the begin by importing git_role first is not work as "repos" list of dict filling while playbooks run, and at start it's empty yet.

I feel the only way here is having little extra code across all roles which invoke "git" module ansible to clone repo. 

Thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind, I already realized that just need import task per role tasks level, not in main playbook. And this work fine. Thanks. I import task clone_repos from role git_role in being import it inherits variables from this particular role where it was imported, not from git_role. And it what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(ansible 2.7.9)

It is possible to combine dictionaries from different roles. Let's have roles role_A, role_B, and role_C with default variables.

```
$ cat roles/role_A/defaults/main.yml
repos_A:
  name_of_repo_A:
    url: "git@myrepo.com"
    path: "/path/on/local_system"
    branch: "branch_to_checkout"

$ cat roles/role_B/defaults/main.yml
repos_B:
  name_of_repo_B:
    url: "git@myrepo.com"
    path: "/path/on/local_system"
    branch: "branch_to_checkout"

$ cat roles/role_C/defaults/main.yml
repos_C:
  name_of_repo_C:
    url: "git@myrepo.com"
    path: "/path/on/local_system"
    branch: "branch_to_checkout"
```

If the names of the dictionaries follow the names of the roles `repos_<SECOND-PART-OF-ROLE-NAME>` then the play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - role_A
    - role_B
    - role_C
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        repos: "{{ repos|default({})|
                   combine(lookup('vars',
                                  'repos_' ~ item.split('_').1,
                                   default={}))
                   }}"
      loop: "{{ role_names }}"
    - debug:
        var: repos
```

gives the combined directory

```
"repos": {
    "name_of_repo_A": {
        "branch": "branch_to_checkout", 
        "path": "/path/on/local_system", 
        "url": "git@myrepo.com"
    }, 
    "name_of_repo_B": {
        "branch": "branch_to_checkout", 
        "path": "/path/on/local_system", 
        "url": "git@myrepo.com"
    }, 
    "name_of_repo_C": {
        "branch": "branch_to_checkout", 
        "path": "/path/on/local_system", 
        "url": "git@myrepo.com"
    }
}
```

**Control repos inside roles**

It is possible to control the *repos* inside the roles. Let's put the tasks below into the roles and introduce the variable *repos_source*

```
$ cat roles/role_A/tasks/main.yml
- set_fact:
    repos: {}
- set_fact:
    repos: "{{ repos|
               combine(lookup('vars',
                              'repos_' ~ item.split('_').1,
                               default={}))
                }}"
  loop: "{{ repos_source }}"
- debug:
    var: repos
```

The tasks below

```
- import_role:
    name: role_A
  vars:
    repos_source:
      - role_A
      - role_C

- import_role:
    name: role_B
  vars:
    repos_source:
      - role_A
      - role_B

- import_role:
    name: role_C
  vars:
    repos_source:
      - role_B
      - role_C
```

give

```
TASK [role_A : debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "repos": {
        "name_of_repo_A": {
            "branch": "branch_to_checkout", 
            "path": "/path/on/local_system", 
            "url": "git@myrepo.com"
        }
        "name_of_repo_C": {
            "branch": "branch_to_checkout", 
            "path": "/path/on/local_system", 
            "url": "git@myrepo.com"
        }
    }
}

TASK [role_B : debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "repos": {
        "name_of_repo_A": {
            "branch": "branch_to_checkout", 
            "path": "/path/on/local_system", 
            "url": "git@myrepo.com"
        }, 
        "name_of_repo_B": {
            "branch": "branch_to_checkout", 
            "path": "/path/on/local_system", 
            "url": "git@myrepo.com"
        }
    }
}

TASK [role_C : debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "repos": {
        "name_of_repo_B": {
            "branch": "branch_to_checkout", 
            "path": "/path/on/local_system", 
            "url": "git@myrepo.com"
        }, 
        "name_of_repo_C": {
            "branch": "branch_to_checkout", 
            "path": "/path/on/local_system", 
            "url": "git@myrepo.com"
        }
    }
}
```

---

NOTE
In ansible 2.8 use `ansible_play_role_names` or `ansible_role_names`. See [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html).

Comment: This is a good, smart way which I didn't see, I will definitely use it in future tasks, thanks. But for current problem it's I think fit little less, because in this case all repos will be cloned in some defined by user time of playbook running. But for me better that specified repo will be cloned at time running each role where it was specified in vars.

Comment: It's possible to "Control repos inside roles". I've added the section.